# How can I configure my Pytorch Llama2 13b model to make use of both my GPU's

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, llama

I have currently 2 NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 GPU's and my model is currently only using one of them. What configuration am I missing?

```
import locale
locale.getpreferredencoding = lambda: "UTF-8"

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, message="You seem to be using the pipelines sequentially on GPU.")

# %pip install accelerate einops langchain -q
# %pip install --upgrade transformers==4.31.0 -q
# %pip install numpy -q
# %pip install scipy -q
# %pip install pandas -q

import torch
import transformers

from transformers import AutoTokenizer

import pandas as pd
import random
import re

torch.cuda.current_device() # 0
torch.cuda.device_count() # 2
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0) # 'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080'

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print('Using device:', device) # Using device: cuda

import torch.nn as nn
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer, pipeline

model_name = "Llama-2-13b-hf"

tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

pipeline = pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model_name, 
    torch_dtype=torch.float16,
    device_map="auto",
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)
```

I tried using the transformers pipeline:

```
sequences.append(
    pipeline(
        prompt,
        top_k=10,
        max_new_tokens=150,
        num_return_sequences=1,
    )
)

for sequence in sequences:
    generated_text = sequence[0]['generated_text']
    experiment_result.append(generated_text)
```

But I get:

\lib\site-packages\accelerate\utils\modeling.py:317, in set_module_tensor_to_device(module, tensor_name, device, value, dtype, fp16_statistics)
315             module._parameters[tensor_name] = param_cls(new_value, requires_grad=old_value.requires_grad)
316 elif isinstance(value, torch.Tensor):
--> 317     new_value = value.to(device)
318 else:
319     new_value = torch.tensor(value, device=device)

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 136.00 MiB (GPU 0; 10.00 GiB total capacity; 9.05 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 9.24 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g38TM.png)

Comment: It's pretty hard and likely also inefficient to split one model between multiple GPUs for inference.